# possible to dockerize existing system?

Tags: docker

Would there possibly be a way to dockerize an existing machine?
I setup a hairy install a while back and will waste days getting it running again unless i can simply dockerize that system somehow and run it elsewhere.

Comment: I suggest to look into tools that can turn your server into a virtual machine. Containers are not the same thing.